# how to know if listview scroll has reached the bottom/Top

Tags: android, listview

I have an android program and I want to know when the user scrolled to the bottom/ top of a listview. The thing is: I scroll the list by using buttons and the smoothScrollBy method.

Tried using this for bottom, but doesn't work, I still get the last element still "half-cut"

```
if (yourListView.getLastVisiblePosition() == yourListView.getAdapter().getCount() -1 &&
yourListView.getChildAt(yourListView.getChildCount() - 1).getBottom() <= yourListView.getHeight()) {

    //It is scrolled all the way down here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement **OnScrollListener** in your Activity then override *onScroll method* and add the following code :

```
@Override public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem >= totalItemCount){
        System.out.println("you reached the bottom");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but this answer is still not complete: It reaches bottom without being really the bottom, I mean, it reaches at the last element of the list, but it's half-cut